# Increment z-index dynamically with Less

Tags: html, css, loops, less, z-index

I'm trying to increment the z-index of elements of class `.box` as they appear dynamically in the browser without using any JavaScript/jQuery. I've tried using the native css `counter-increment`, but that is only useful for displaying numbers on screen:

```
    .container {
        counter-reset: indexvalue;
    }

    .box {
        position: relative;
        counter-increment: indexvalue;
        z-index: counter(indexvalue);
    }
```

So using `Less`, please how can I increment the z-index of each `.box` as they appear on screen?

Many Thanks

Comment: It's impossible since Less has no knowledge of the HTML you'll be using the generated CSS in.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that.

Less compiler just creates the CSS file once on "compile time".

What you try to accomplish would be in "run time".